# Show that: $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm struggling with this one, and I don't understand how the sum can be correct then you get $0$ in the bottom of the fraction then $n=0$. Can anyone explain?

It might have something to do with this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html

Comment: Do you know (or can take for granted) that for $x\in (-1,1)$, $$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$? (And what do you know about power series — namely, about theorems of derivation and integration under the sum?)

Comment: Yeah, maybe the task is written wrong in the book

Comment: I think, besides the fact that the RHS is infinite, the series is wrong.

Comment: Yes i know that what you said is the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: @stenvikteam Then integrate the RHS of what is given in my comment above: what do you get? (The thing you are trying to prove is not the right expression, but this will allow you to find the right one)

Comment: the above identity is certainly not true. the rhs is the power series of $\log(1+x)$ + plus the infinite $n=0$ term

Comment: @ClementC. I obtain 1 divded by (x-1)^2 but im working with (x+1)^2

Comment: @stenvikteam: How do you get that by integrating the RHS (term by term)? You should get a series (integrating the LHS would be the second step) (and as the above comments say -- my first reaction was blatantly wrong) the indices should indeed start at $n=1$ in the question)

Comment: @ClementC. I mean if I intergrate LHS i get 1/(x-1)^2 and not 1/(x+1)^2 which is my own LHS. So I don't understand how this is going to help me

Comment: @stenvikteam If you *integrate* the LHS (i.e., the $\frac{1}{1-x}$  in my comment) between say $0$ and $x$, you will not get a rational function -- you'll get $-\ln(1-x)$.

Comment: People are too hasty in putting questions on hold.  The fact that there are errors is not a reason to close the question.  That a coherent answer can still be given might be seen by looking at my answer below. $\qquad$

Comment: @ClementC.  -ln(1-x) + C wow im stupid (-_-)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n = \frac 1 {1+x}.
$$
Antidifferentiating the series, we get
\begin{align}
& \text{constant} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^{n+1}} {n+1} = \text{constant} + \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac {(-x)^m} m \quad \text{where }m = n+1 \\[10pt]
= {} & \text{constant} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-x)^n} n
\end{align}
Antidifferentiating the other side, we get
$$
\log_e |1+x| + \text{constant}.
$$
(Here, "constant" has to mean a *piecewise* constant, with one value for $x>-1$ and another for $x<-1$.)

So I'm guessing that in some sort of attempt to do something like the above, some mistakes happened along the way.

Comment: So there are no way to confirm that the constant on RHS and LHS equal to 0?

Comment: @stenvikteam : Yes: any constant at all that you put there will be correct. If you have additional information, you might be able to find the value of the constant. $\qquad$

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.